# jenkins : 2 types of users connection

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins instance that users can connect to by using LDAP authentication.
Now, I want to give the access to another user whom doesn't have an LDAP account, so I am wondering if there is any configuration (or plugin) in jenkins so I can check 'Jenkins user database' and 'LDAP' in the Jenkins Security Realm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a feature requested some time ago and still [in progress](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3404).

However if you are on a Unix based system, the suggested solution is to to [use PAM](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Mixed-mode-authentication-td3447248.html) and let the OS authenticate the users.